# Update an attribute value on change

Tags: javascript, input, attributes, event-listener

i have this:

`<p>Qté : ${quantity}</p> <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="100" value="${quantity}">`being added dynamically in html for each product of a cart.

I want that input to update inside "p"tag and inside the cart when there a change inside this input.
But lets say for now that i want to update inside "p"tag and value when i change the number with arrow or type it.
`value="${quantity}"` --> that code is saying take the quantity for this product (in cart/localstorage) and set it to default.

i want the changed value to be the new default, if you know what i mean.
And i also need this to work for all the products, for now it only works with the first item fo the cart.

for now i'm stuck with

```
const quantityBox = document.querySelector(".itemQuantity");   
      quantityBox.addEventListener("change", function () {
    //update value function   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, I think what you want is:

1. There are many products and each product has 'p' for display quantity and 'input' for change quantity.
2. When 'input' tag value is changed, matching 'p' tag text should be changed, too.

I think you can use Element.previousElementSibling like this:

```
const quantityBox = document.querySelector(".itemQuantity");   
quantityBox.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    const prevP = e.target.previousElementSibling;
    prevP.innerText = "Qté : " + e.target.value;
});
```

Comment: that works perfectly, i never thought of previousElementSibling! thank you.
now i'll just add an other line or function to tell it to use that "e.target.value" and update the quantity inside cart/localStorage.

Comment: Happy that my answer was helpful. Have a nice day, Redhewlett!